# Find the fundamental group of $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the unit square with corners identified. I was thinking about its fundamental group. My strategy was to visualize it as e CW complex with a single $0$-cell, four $1$-cells (i.e a wedge of four circles) and a $2$-cell attached along the $1$-cells. This will create a relation and $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your space is homeomorphic to the torus $\mathbb T^2$ hence $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(\mathbb T^2)=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is there any way how to see this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any further, my algebraic topology knowledge is very limited =( You can find more information about the fundamental group in the book "Fundamental group and covering spaces (E. Lages Lima)" however he doesn't deal with CW-complexes. For this approach you could check Hatcher's algebraic topology book (I don't really like that book, but it's the one that comes into my mind now).

Comment: @PtF $X$ is not isomorphic to a torus.

Comment: @xhimi I think that your argument is completely correct!

Comment: It looks like it's just $\langle a, b, c, d | abcd = 1 \rangle$. You can, too,  use van Kampen theorem in the covers given by a sphere with a disk removed and a wedge of four circles multiplied by an interval.

Comment: Anyway, it's $\mathbb{Z}^{* 3}$ as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to see that $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to the free group with three generators. First of all, by thickening the unique $0$-cell in $X$, one see that $X$ is homotopic equivalent to the sphere minus four points. Then using the stereographic projection, this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ minus three points. Thus it's fundamental group is $\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

[Note: I don't have enough reputation points (yet) to include images]

You have the unit square, with edges identified as $A, B, C$, and $D$, respectively, along with vertices $v, v, v,$ and $v$. We will call the square under this identification $X$. Let $U$ be an interior disk of the unit square, let $V$ be the 'boundary' of the unit square such that $U \cap V$ is an annulus intersection in the interior of the square. $U$ is contractible and $V$ deformation retracts onto its edges, which is homeomorphic to the wedge of four circles. Then $U \cap V$ has fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, as it has $S^1$ a deformation retract. We apply Siefert-Van Kampen directly, yielding $\pi_{1}(X) \cong \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \space | \space \alpha\beta\gamma\delta = 1\} \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ with the given quotient.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I can see that $\pi_{1}(X) \cong \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \space | \space \alpha\beta\gamma\delta = 1\}$. What I'm having troubles is to show that the latter is precisely $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @xhimi Note that $\delta = (\alpha \beta \gamma)^{-1}$, so we can throw away $\delta$ and the rest have no relationships.

Comment: @xhimi: AreaMan is correct. Notice that three of the generators uniquely determine the fourth through this relation. The picture here is that, by attaching a 2-cell, you have changed the fundamental group from that of the wedge of four circles explicitly. This happens because the 2-cell has an orientation, it isn't just 'there'. I hope that helps.